# Declaring a prototype within a function vs outside a function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, prototype

I would like to know if there is a difference between the following in JavaScript:

```
function Person(name, family) {
    this.name = name;
    this.family = family;
}

Person.prototype.getFull = function() {
    return this.name + " " + this.family;
};
```

and

```
function Person(name, family) {
    this.name = name;
    this.family = family;
    Person.prototype.getFull = function() {
       return this.name + " " + this.family;
    };
}
```

Comment: right, it works. but it overwrites for every instance.

Comment: the 2nd one re-declares the method for all instance upon each instance creation, which is not ideal, even if it works (since there's no closures)

Comment: Like pointed out the second one is re-creating the method everytime,.  You could of course check if the method exists then create, but then it's getting untidy,.. So the first method is norm..  ps, if you find the first one tedious, you can always create an alias,.. eg.. `const $p = Person.prototype;  $p.getFull = ....; $p.something = .... etc.`.  And of course another idea is to use ES6 classes, and it will do the prototype bit for you.